# php checking Prepared statements in if statements

Tags: php, html, search-engine

Hello I am currently having problems with if statements in php with prepared statements, no matter what I enter my when checking get_result my statements are always true. I honestly have no idea what Im doing I am very new to php and the concept of prepared statements.

```
$searchtext= $_POST['search-box'];
$sqlName= $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE ? ");
                $sqlName->bind_param("s", $searchtext);
                $sqlName->execute();

                $NameResult = $sqlName->get_result();

                $sqltext= $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGKeywords LIKE ? ");
                $sqltext->bind_param("s", $searchtext);
                $sqltext->execute();

                $TextResult = $sqltext->get_result();
if($NameResult->num_rows > 0 || $TextResult->num_rows > 0){
                        if($NameResult->num_rows > 0 ){
                            echo "made it into sqlname";
                            while($rs = $NameResult->fetch_assoc()){
                                echo "name result";

                                ?>
                                <div class="row resultcontent">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                            <div class="contshading">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                            <h1><?php echo "name".$rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if($count<10){
                            echo "exploded result";
                            foreach($searchbit as $value){
                                $temp = '%'.$value.'%';
                                $sqlvalue= $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE ? OR PGKeyword LIKE ? ");

                                $sqlvalue->bind_param("ss", $temp, $temp);
                                $sqlvalue->execute();
                                $ValueResult = $sqlvalue->get_result();

                                if($ValueResult->num_rows > 0){
                                    while($rs = $ValueResult->fetch_assoc()){
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="row resultcontent">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                                                <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                                    <div class="contshading">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                                    <h1><?php echo "name".$rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                        $count++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            while($rs = $TextResult->fetch_assoc()){
                                ?>
                                <div class="row resultcontent">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                            <div class="contshading">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                            <h1><?php echo "name".$rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $count++;
                            }


                        }
```

I have tried if(!$result), if($result->num_rows>0), if($result->affected_rows) and others but none seem to work has anybody got any idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sorry, but please shorten that "wall of code" to a minimal example demonstrating the issue. No one wants to work through all of that.

Comment: @arkascha sorry about that I cleaned it up

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance you don't have the "native driver" (mysqlnd) installed, which is necessary for the `get_result()` method.

cf. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Try using PDO:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO(
  'mysql:dbname=myDatabase;host=myHost', 
  'myUsername', 'myPassword');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE ? ');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $searchtext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I have just checked my phpinfo.php and mysqlnd is enabled, also the get_result seems to work it is just any if statements relating to it always seem to be true when they should be false but still true when true, it is as if the if statement was not there at all. it is very strange. For PDO do you not need to install something because if so I cannot use it as I am renting a server.

Comment: After assigning your result set to $TextResult, could you show me what the result of `var_dump($TextResult); exit;` would be?

Comment: When the result should be true i get this: object(mysqli_result)#6 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(8) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }    If it should fail it I get no result. NameResult gets the same as previous when it is suppose to be true but also gets the same result when it is suppose to be false.

Comment: Then the only options left are that a) no records match your query; b) your binding is building a query you're not expecting. Have you tried to debug by putting "$stmt->error" after each mysqli call?

Comment: I just tried printing the error but i get no reports and if no records match my query should it not fail my if statements as that is what my if statements are trying to achieve, a way of checking if the query actually found any records and if it did not it should move on.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that maybe new to php, prepared statements and having similar problems to me, I solved my problems by switching get_result to store_result after changing code to suit store_result things seemed to work flawlessly. Here is my new code it still needs some fixing and cleaning up but I hope this helps someone in need.

```
$sqlname= $connect->prepare("SELECT PGID, PGName, PGUrl, PGImgUrl FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE ? ");
                $sqlname->bind_param("s", $searchtext);
                $sqlname->execute();
                $sqlname->store_result();

                $sqltext= $connect->prepare("SELECT PGID, PGName, PGUrl, PGImgUrl FROM SearchPG WHERE PGKeywords LIKE ? ");
                $sqltext->bind_param("s", $searchtext);
                $sqltext->execute();
                $sqltext->store_result();
if($sqlname->num_rows > 0 || $sqltext->num_rows > 0){
                        if($sqlname->num_rows > 0 ){
                            $sqlname->bind_result($id, $name, $url, $imgurl);

                            while($rs = $sqlname->fetch()){


                                ?>
                                <div class="row resultcontent">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $imgurl;?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                            <div class="contshading">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                            <h1><?php echo "name".$name;?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if($count<10){


                            if($words > 1){
                            foreach($searchbit as $value){

                                $temp = '%'.$value.'%';
                                $sqlvalue= $connect->prepare("SELECT PGID, PGName, PGUrl, PGImgUrl FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE ? OR PGKeywords LIKE ? ");
                                if ( false===$sqlvalue ) {
                                    die('connect failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($sqlvalue->error));
                                }
                                $sqlvalue->bind_param("ss", $temp, $temp);
                                if ( false===$sqlvalue ) {
                                    die('bind failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($sqlvalue->error));
                                }
                                $sqlvalue->execute();
                                if ( false===$sqlvaue ) {
                                    die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($sqlvalue->error));
                                }
                                $sqlvalue->store_result();

                                //$ValueResult = $sqlvalue->get_result();

                                if($sqlvalue->num_rows > 0){
                                    $sqlvalue->bind_result($id, $name, $url, $imgurl);
                                    while($rs = $sqlvalue->fetch()){
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="row resultcontent">
                                            <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
                                                <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $imgurl;?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                                    <div class="contshading">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                                    <h1><?php echo "name".$name;?></h1>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                        $count++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            }
                            $sqltext->bind_result($id, $name, $url, $imgurl);

                            while($rs = $sqltext->fetch()){
                                echo "made it into the loop";
                                ?>
                                <div class="row resultcontent">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $imgurl;?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                            <div class="contshading">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                            <h1><?php echo "name".$name;?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $count++;
                            }


                        }
                    }
```